# Kaminari problems while upgrading to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin, kaminari

We are upgrading a rails app from v3 to v5 and are using ActiveAdmin which has a dependency on Kaminari. In this process we had to change all our models to inherit from `ApplicationRecord` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base`. This change results in the following errors:

```
undefined method `per_page_kaminari' for #Team::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00555f215eb200
```

where `Team` is a model that was previously inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` and was changed to inherit from `ApplicationRecord`. Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at [this issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2537), particularly [this comment](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2537#issuecomment-27645309)? Looks much similar to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by placing the following code at the bottom of the `application.rb` file.

```
class Application < Rails::Application

    ...

    # Initialize Kaminari before the appropriate models loading.
    Kaminari.configure do |config|
      config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Same problem was facing by me as well

It's because of the conflicts on the will paginate and kaminari

Add the file in initializers/ folder

```
 Kaminari.configure do |config|
   config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
 end
```